# Can we use "are" with "be" in english sentences and when it correct?

Tags: passive-voice

I am learning English and would like to understand if we can use are with be in the same sentences. As I understand be comes with passive. So, my question is, is it correct to say:

These jackets are most likely to be sold very quickly than other jackets design.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's *absolutely* okay! Such construction is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for the most part you are correct, but I want to edit your statement a little bit so that it *be* correct:

> These jackets *are* **more** likely to be sold very quickly than other
>   **jacket designs**. (present indicative form of "to be")

As you can see, "are" is the third-person plural present indicative conjugation of the verb "to be" whereas "be", in this instance, would be the third-person plural present subjunctive conjugation of "to be":

> It is imperative that these jackets *be* more likely to be sold very
>   quickly than other jacket designs. (present subjunctive form of "to
>   be")

As you can see above wherein I mention that I want to edit your statement "so that it *be* correct", I have italicized *be* in the phrase "it be" to show you a present subjunctive conjugation of "to be" in third-person singular wherein the present indicative conjugational form would be *is* as in "it is".  To make a long story short, you have used the conjugation of "to be" correctly in your example as "are" is the correct conjugational form therein.

I hope this might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.